# How to initialize or assign 中文 to wstring?

Tags: c++, unicode, wstring

I tried to use L"string", but it doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    wstring wstr = L"你好";//[Error] converting to execution character set: Illegal byte sequence
    wcout<<wstr<<endl;
}
```

Use wcin and input 中文 works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    wstring wstr;
    wcin>>wstr;//Input Chinese is OK
    wcout<<wstr<<endl;
}
```

How to initialize or assign 中文 to wstring?

**Edit**: I tried some online compilers. They all can compile but all output "??".

e.g. cpp.sh jdoodle onlinegdb repl.it

**Edit 2**: I installed g++ i868 MinGW-W64 8.1.0. Use Visual Studio to save the cpp file as utf8 format. Then use command line to compile it. It still output nothing.

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: I tried TCM-GCC 4.9.2 in windows 10 and g++ (GCC) 4.4.7 in linux. Both failed.

Comment: These are ancient compilers, you can see what a proper compiler should do here, and with a new one it works: https://gcc.godbolt.org/

Comment: Ensure that your file is encoded in same way as compiler reads file. Most probably this is UTF-8.

Comment: Depending on what you intend to do, could be a good idea to read texts from a file. Possibly you need to convert utf-8 input to local system encoding (espcially on windows; most linux distributions internally use utf-8 natively already). That might help you with internationalisation of your programme (just swap files; possibly better: one file with different translations in different columns, or XML-based). For utf-8 conversion, there are libraries, such as [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Comment: This must be configuration issue (file encoding vs what encoding compiler uses). Most compilers with default settings do not have a problem with this code: https://godbolt.org/z/mU4CpD (I do not see `TCM-GCC 4.9.2` on godbolt but it is gcc after all).

Comment: I tried cpp.sh. It can compile the code with L"你好". But output ??.

Comment: But I use wcin then use wcout, it works fine. Why?

Comment: @蔡易翔 Because those features read bytes and emit bytes. When you try to provide the input using a string literal, you add another factor: the encoding of the source code file, and the ability of the compiler to interpret the source code in that encoding.

Comment: Try typing in the two characters you want (as in your working code) and then output the 'Unicode' values of these, with: `printf("%04X %04X\n", wstr[0], wstr[1]);` - this may give us some clues about the 'code page' your console/compiler is using. Tell us what values you get for 中文.

Answer (score 5):

Your compiler clearly doesn't like Unicode characters in its source files. Try initializing your string with Unicode escapes, instead:

```
wstring wstr = L"\u4E2D\u6587"; // These MAY be the correct codes.
```

Where `4E2D` and `6587` are replaced with the actual hexadecimal values for the characters you want. (Sorry, but I don't have access to a full Unicode table for Chinese characters: I tried pasting them into my compiler, and these are the values it gave me on translating.)

The Unicode values given are for the character string in your question (中文); for the (different - 你好) one in your posted code, use `L"\u4F60\u597D"`.

Also see the answer by @MarekR.

Comment: Can compile but print nothing in windows and ?? in linux.

Comment: @蔡易翔 Can you try again with the modified Unicode values?

Comment: @蔡易翔 • can you save the output to a file, and then examine the file with a hex dump utility?  I can imagine those old compilers may not be using the newer Windows 10 APIs that handle Unicode better for I/O.

Comment: @蔡易翔 - Maybe try setting your console font to something you know has full Unicode support, like `Arial Unicode MS` (in Windows).

Answer (score 3):

This must be configuration issue!

Apparently your compiler uses different encoding then your file is written in!
Since you are using Windows most probably encoding of file on your machine is not UTF-8 (end you have copied this file to Linux), but something else.
Since gcc is more Linux friendly it may expect UTF-8 and you have an conflict.

This is common problem, since Windows for a long time did maintain some backward compatibility with DOS (where only single byte characters where allowed and system used code pages for respective languages).

As you [can see here](https://godbolt.org/z/I7vbXV),  most compilers with default settings do not have a problem with code which uses Chinese characters.
I do not see `TCM-GCC 4.9.2` compiler on godbolt, but it is not very old gcc after all.

I recommend ensure that code is written in UTF-8 and compiler will treat sources as UTF-8 encoded.

**Edit**: Adding `std::locale::global(std::locale(""));` made your code properly displaying this string on godbolt.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in Visual Studio. It works(outputs "你好") if I saved my C++ file to either Unicode or utf8 format. Can you try saving your c++ file to either Unicode or utf8?

Comment: I can't even compile it in Visual Studio 2017. It said the operator << after wcout is wrong. But this might be another problem. I am not familiar with VS.

Comment: I saved the files to Unicode and utf8. I try to use another tools to compile.